# Property of the Circle Metric $d(x,y) := \inf_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} |x-y+k|$ on $[0,1[$.

Tags: general-topology, inequality, metric-spaces, dynamical-systems, circles

If we endow $[0,1[$ with the metric 
$$d(x,y) := \inf_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} |x-y+k|,$$ 
then $[0,1[$ is homeomorphic to $S^{1}$. For a fixed $N\in\mathbb{N}$ we consider the map 
$$f\colon [0,1[\rightarrow [0,1[, \qquad f(x):= Nx - \lfloor Nx\rfloor = Nx \mod 1.$$ 
Given an integer $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we can compare orbit segments of length $n$ with the metric 
$$d_{n}(x,y) := \max_{0\leq j\leq n-1}d(f^{j}(x),f^{j}(y)).$$
I want to prove that if $d_{n}(x,y)<1/N$, then $d_{n}(x,y) = N^{n-1}|x-y|$.

It is not hard to prove that $d_{n}(x,y)\leq N^{n-1}d(x,y)\leq N^{n-1}|x-y|$, even without the assumption that $d_{n}(x,y)<1/N$. Any suggestions for the other inequality (i.e. $d_{n}(x,y) \geq N^{n-1}|x-y|$) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you didn't use yet the assumption. How about using it?

Comment: I think that my main struggle is that the assumption is a bound for $d_{n}(x,y)(<1/N)$ from above. While I want to prove a bound from below. $d_{n}(x,y)\geq N^{n-1}|x-y|$.

Comment: See $S^1$ as a circle and notice that if you apply too many times two points $x$ and $y$ they will pass from distance $<\frac12$ **possibly again to distance $<\frac12$**. Make a drawing.

Comment: @JohnB Since the word ‘circle’ is in the title ànd in the tags, I think OP already knows that he can view this space as the unit circle. I think he is looking for a formal proof, which, in my opinion, is surprisingly enough not straightforward.

Comment: @Calculix Sorry to disagree, the proof is a very simple exercise and thus why it is appropriate to remind that $S^1$ is a circle.

Comment: @JohnB Whether it is an easy exercise or not, he is clearly not understanding. Otherwise he wouldn’t be here, would he? If you think something is easy, then that does not necessarily imply that someone else thinks it is easy. If it is really that easy, I think you should at least convince him (and me) why it is easy. Just telling someone that it is easy, and leaving it at that without any further proper explanation is just a bit rude, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The distance $d$ that you describe is the distance of two points $x$, $y$ if we imagine them being on $\mathcal{S}^1$. If  $d(x,y)<1/N$ then it is easy to see that $d(f(x),f(y))=Nd(x,y)$ (if you imagine the points being complex numbers on the unit circle the function $f$ simply multiplies their arguments by $N$). Now the condition $$d_n(x,y)<1/N,$$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, implies that $d(f^i(x),f^i(y))<1/N,$ for all $ i\leq n-1$. Hence $$d(f^i(x),f^i(y))=Nd\left(f^{i-1}(x),f^{i-1}(y)\right)=N^i d(x,y), \text{for all}\hspace{1mm} 1\leq i\leq n-1.$$ Obviously the biggest number among these is $$d\left(f^{n-1}(x),f^{n-1}(y)\right)=N^{n-1}d(x,y)=N^{n-1}|x-y|,$$ where the last equality holds because $d(x,y)$ is small. Thus $d_n(x,y)=N^{n-1}|x-y|$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Could you elaborate on the equation $d(f(x),f(y)) = Nd(x,y)$ without refering to the unit circle? Since I can't prove it formally.

Comment: I actually think that the claim is false. Namely pick $N = 3$, $x = 1/4$ and $y=0$. Then $d(x,y) = 1/4<1/3$ and $d(f(x)),f(y)) = d(3/4,0) = 1/4\neq 3\cdot d(x,y) = 3/4$.

Comment: You are right my attempt is problematic but I think that the same can be said about the exercise because $d(f(x),f(y))=d(x,y)=1/4$ which means $d_2(x,y)=1/4$ and not $3/4$ as the exercise tells you.