# Relation between Expanding Circle Map $x\mapsto Nx \ \operatorname{mod} \ 1$ and the Metric $d(x,y) = \inf_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}|x-y+k|$ on $[0,1[$.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces, modular-arithmetic, dynamical-systems

This question is related to a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3655193/property-of-the-circle-metric-dx-y-inf-k-in-mathbbz-x-yk-on-0-1) I asked yesterday, but formulated more directly.

If we endow $[0,1[$ with the metric 
$$d(x,y) := \inf_{k\in\mathbb{Z}} |x-y+k|,$$ 
then $[0,1[$ is homeomorphic to $S^{1}$. For a fixed $N\in\mathbb{N}$ we consider the expanding map 
$$f\colon [0,1[\rightarrow [0,1[, \qquad f(x):= Nx - \lfloor Nx\rfloor = Nx \mod 1.$$

Let $n$ a positive integer and assume that $d(x,y)\leq 1/2N^{n}$. I have the following three related questions:

1. Can we conclude that $$d(f^{n}(x),f^{n}(y)) = N^{n}d(x,y)?$$
2. Does the distance between the first $n$ iterations increase, i.e. $$d(f^{n}(x),f^{n}(y)) \geq d(f^{n-1}(x),f^{n-1}(y)) \geq \ldots \geq d(f(x),f(y)) \geq d(x,y)?$$ If 1. is true for all $0\leqslant j\leqslant n$, then this follows easily.
3. Can we also conclude that $$d(x,y) = |x-y|?$$

I know how to visualize these properties on the circle, but I don't know how to prove this rigorously. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you take the input of distance mod 1 ?

Comment: @EDX Yes, $\operatorname{mod} 1$ is hidden in the definition of $f$.

Comment: So mod 1  $f^n(x)-f^n(y)=N^n(x-y)$ so it is direct for 1 and 2.

Comment: @EDX This is indeed true, but how to deal with the infimum in the definition of $d$. I mean, we have by this identity that $d(f^{n}(x),f^{n}(y)) = \inf_{k}|N^{n}(x-y) + k|$. But $d(x,y) = \inf_{k}|x-y + k|$.

Comment: If you consider you input values mod 1 it is necessary to consider the whole expression involving them. So $N^n(x-y)+k=N^n(x-y)$ mod 1 because $k$ is a whole number. So you're not on $[0,1[$ but on $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ of course homeomorph but not the same kind of members. Its why $d(x,y)_[0,1[$ is equivalent to $d(x,y)_{\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}}$ rigourously speaking. A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is not rigoursously equal to a quotiented space of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @EDX Sorry for the confusion. The notation mod1 here is a lazy way of writing Nx−⌊Nx⌋, so I am not dealing with equivalence classes here. But notice that we still have $d(f^{n}(x),f^{n}(y)) = \inf_{k}|N^{n}(x-y) + k|$.

Comment: Yes, but $k$ is relative number so the difference of floor is relative so taking the min on just $N^n(x-y) $ is enough.

Comment: That means that inside your distance you can calculate mod 1. In which space do you consider the distance in the last question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but $k$ is relative number so the difference of floor is relative so taking the min on just $N^n(x-y) $ is enough.

Comment: Sorry I don't manage to delete that answer which has its place in comments.